# Как убрать отступы в ListView

Tags: android

В элементах между `ListView` небольшой просвет с цвет родителя, в котором находится `ListView`, как на фото (для наглядности поставил родителю красный цвет):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Адаптер стоит самый простой (самодельный), в нем размеры никак не затрагиваются, в разметке то же самое, никаких отступов не указывается, тем более, они были бы между элементами `ListView`, да и не первый раз с таким сталкиваюсь. Как можно убрать эти отступы?

Comment: Если ответ решает заявленную в вопросе задачу, то вы можете отметить его верным

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, как Вы добрались до этого вопроса?)

Comment: Кто-целенаправленно шерстит подряд все прошлогодние вопросы и ставит плюсы на нулевые ответы. Вот и на этот поставили и я через уведомление сюда попал)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<ListView

    <!-- divider  -->
    android:divider="@null"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp" >

</ListView>
```